# JAX-RS (REST Easy) InMemoryClientExecutor/ClientRequest Exception

Tags: java, web-services, exception, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm trying to use the InMemoryClientExecutor to call services on my local JVM which return javax.ws.rs.core.Response objects.  I can get this to work but only by specifying the String type like so:

```
String response = new ClientRequest("/myService", executor)
    .get(String.class)
    .getEntity();
```

Since the signature of the service is like so:

```
@GET
@Path("/myService")
public Response getSomeData(@Form MyFormBean bean) {
    //...blah...
}
```

However I would like to get the actual Response objects back so that I can get the entities out and return those objects in my new "aggregate" response.  When I just return the string the Jackson Parser doesn't see this as JSON, just a regular string so it does things like encoding line breaks into \n, etc.

Whenever I do something like:

```
String response = new ClientRequest("/myService",executor)
    .get(Response.class)
    .getEntity();
```

or even this to just get the plain request object:

```
String response = new ClientRequest("/myService", executor).get().getEntity();
```

I get the following Exception:

```
Exception Occured: org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponseFailure: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/json and type null
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.createResponseFailure(BaseClientResponse.java:523)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.createResponseFailure(BaseClientResponse.java:514)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.readFrom(BaseClientResponse.java:415)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.getEntity(BaseClientResponse.java:377)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.BaseClientResponse.getEntity(BaseClientResponse.java:338)
```

Also present further down is:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet Resteasy threw exception: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.LoggableFailure: Unable to find contextual data of type: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ContextParameterInjector$GenericDelegatingProxy.invoke(ContextParameterInjector.java:56)
    at $Proxy210.getScheme(Unknown Source)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Response` object being returned from the server, just a data stream that, in your case, is the representation of some entity, in JSON format. Trying to deserialize this data back into a Response object on the client side will not work, because effectively you are saying the JSON represents a `Response` object, which it doesn't (it represents the entity that ***used to be contained** in the Response).

Good news is, there are other ways to obtain the entity, which do not require trying to back-spin it into a `Response`. You will need to have the entities on the classpath of your client:

```
MyEntity response = new ClientRequest("/myService", executor)
    .get(MyEntity.class)
    .getEntity();
```

Replace `MyEntity` with the type of the actual entity you are expecting to receive.